# Trying to format php time 12hr no leading zeros

Tags: php, time, string-formatting

I feel stupid asking - but I've had a problem with my time format. Using php and pulling date/time from a MySQL db I am trying to format a time display so there are no leading zero characters in my 12 hour format. A space is fine.. Sounds easy right. Probably is...

Style I want is : `6:00 PM` NOT `06:00 PM`

`$result[0][0]` is the value of `"2013-06-06 18:00:00"`

PHP code is now:

```
echo strftime('%I:%M %p', strtotime($result[0][0]));
//upper case "i" WORKS but has leading zero
```

PHP code I think I need is :

```
echo strftime('%l:%M %p', strtotime($result[0][0]));
//Lower case "L" Provides no output
```

Latter is because according to php manual:
using `%l` (lower-case 'L') yeilds Hour in 12-hour format, with a space preceding single digits 1 through 12

But when I use this format I get nothing!

What SIMPLE thing am I doing wrong?

(Hmmm , funny how the codes above look exactly alike in the StackOverflow screen but I am typing Upper case i and lower case L... in fact here is upper i --> "I", and here is lower L -->"l" ??)  They look identical in this font??

Comment: Workaround > [`trim(strftime('%I:%M %p', strtotime($result[0][0])), '0')`](http://php.net/trim).

Comment: Of course! Thanks. I'm obviously too close to the problem. :)
BUT would still like to know why?

Comment: Could you provide original `$result[0][0]` value, please ?

Comment: Yes - is:    2013-06-06 18:00:00

Answer (score 49, accepted):

[***DateTime***](http://php.net/DateTime) doing the trick:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2013-06-06 18:00:00');

echo $date->format('g:i A');
?>
```

Also, [`date()`](http://php.net/date) doing it:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

echo date('g:i A', strtotime('2013-06-06 18:00:00'));
?>
```

Both show:

```
6:00 PM
```

---

[`strftime()`](http://php.net/strftime) looks buggy though. `%l` shows empty string. I tried to put `setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE");` at the top, but it does not help.

Following might be a reason (from [***docs***](http://php.net/strftime)):

> Not all conversion specifiers may be supported by your C library, in
>   which case they will not be supported by PHP's strftime().
>   Additionally, not all platforms support negative timestamps, so your
>   date range may be limited to no earlier than the Unix epoch. This
>   means that %e, %T, %R and, %D (and possibly others) - as well as dates
>   prior to Jan 1, 1970 - will not work on Windows, some Linux
>   distributions, and a few other operating systems. For Windows systems,
>   a complete overview of supported conversion specifiers can be found at
>   » [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak.aspx).

On **MSDN** there is no `%l` format code. It might be a reason, that killing return value. In this case `strftime()` is platform-dependent.

Comment: Agreed as to possibly a buggy issue Re: strftime(). I will use the trim option but nice to know the two more. They also DO work for me as I have just tested each.  Thank you again.

Comment: So maybe this indicates a better approach for formatting such is the date () function, as it seems not to have the same documented platform  and value constraints and issues? I stand enlightened.

Comment: I would prefer `date()`s version. It is better, as there is less function calls, and it is more reliable, because not platform-dependent. Use it instead of `trim(strftime('%I:%M %p', strtotime($result[0][0])), '0')`.

Comment: Yes - after pondering the two approaches it does appear a more direct and efficient approach. Good call, once again.

Comment: i am using this echo date('g:i:s',strtotime($total_time)); but it shows hours 12 if hours are 0 if hours are grater than zero then it shows correct. please help me out

Answer (score 5):

Based on your code, I would also try this to remove the leading zero:

The "g" in PHP, will display the hour without a leading zero.

Time: `<?= echo strftime("g:i:sa", strtotime($result['time'])); ?>`

Comment: echo date('g:i A, strtotime($result['time']))); is right- Why strftime

Answer (score 2):

A PHP datetime object can be formatted without leading zeroes as

```
$DateTime->format('j');
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can use the function below to strip out any leading zeros from strftime

```
       function strip_zeros_from_date( $marked_string="") {
        //remove the marked zero's 
        $no_zeros = str_replace('*0', '', $marked_string);
        //Remove Reaming
        $cleaned_string = str_replace('*', '', $no_zeros);
        return $cleaned_string;

        }
```